Craft 5 Update: Database Views for Content Table No Longer Functioning
I have a custom module on my Craft CMS site that uses a database view by joining the content table and user table. This view consolidates all user details into one place. However, with the Craft CMS 5 update, the content table is no longer utilized.
How can I recreate this view in Craft 5? The functionality of several portions of my website depends on this view, and I am unable to proceed with the update until this issue is resolved.
Thank you for your help!
Example view -
SELECT
   `elements`.`id` AS `UserId`,
   `users`.`username` AS `username`,
   `users`.`firstName` AS `firstName`,
   `users`.`lastName` AS `lastName`,
   `users`.`email` AS `email`,
   `users`.`unverifiedEmail` AS `unverifiedEmail`,
   `users`.`admin` AS `admin`,
   `users`.`locked` AS `locked`,
   `users`.`pending` AS `pending`,
   `users`.`suspended` AS `suspended`,
   `users`.`lastLoginDate` AS `lastLoginDate`,
   `content`.`field_companyAbbrv` AS `field_companyAbbrv`,
   `content`.`field_companyname` AS `field_companyname`,
   `content`.`field_companyReport` AS `field_companyReport`
FROM (((`elements` join `users` 
on(`users`.`id` = `elements`.`id`)) 
join `elements_sites` 
on(`elements_sites`.`elementId` = `elements`.`id`)) 
join `content` on(`content`.`elementId` = `elements`.`id`));```


The old query for the view doesn’t work because, in Craft 5, the content table was moved to a JSON-encoded content column in the element_sites table.
There's not much documentation for how plugin developers can interact with that yet, so you'll probably have to do some code diving.
https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/5.x/CHANGELOG.md#extensibility-2

Elements now store their content in an elements_sites.content column as JSON, rather than across multiple columns in a content table.

Which references these Github issues, which add some context:

https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/2009
https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/4308
https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/7221
https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/7750
https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/12954

